# Modify the product search query

Tags: wordpress, hook-woocommerce

I have replaced the wordpress search engine with the WooCommerce product search engine, that is, to include it in the header of my site I use:
get_product_search_form();
instead of :
get_search_form (true);

I would like the product search engine to also search the product categories.

The problem is that I have a category called "Jackets" but the product in its title and in its content uses the word without the "s" so that if I search for the word "jacket" I get many results, but if I search the word "jackets" (with "s") I do not get any, despite that being the name of the category.

I have thought about modifying the query that makes the request so that it adds something of the type: OR category_name LIKE $ search_term, and I tried to use pre_get_posts in functions.php to modify the query, but it doesn't work.

Could someone help me modify that search query for products so that I can also return the products that are of the category whose name matches with the search term.

Thank you very much in advance!

Kind regards,
Raquel

Answer (score 0):

You can look at this [link](http://jamescollings.co.uk/blog/extending-woocommerce-search-query-include-custom-fields/) .

simple example:

```
// hook into wp pre_get_posts
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'jc_woo_search_pre_get_posts');

function jc_woo_search_pre_get_posts($q){

    if ( is_search() ) {
        add_filter( 'posts_join', 'jc_search_post_join' );
        add_filter( 'posts_where', 'jc_search_post_excerpt' );
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but It doesn't work or I'm doing something wrong, the system changes nothing